# change color of rectangle based on slider's value

Tags: javascript, html

I have html5 canvas and rectangle on it. Second, I have a slider. When user change position of slider the color of rectangle automatically change based on the value of the slider. The range of slider is `0-100`. 0 is for 0 is for color blue and 100 is for red. **How can I achieve this?**

Here is my code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhXQa/)

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="range" id="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
```

js

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    context.fill();
```

Comment: 0 for blue (#0000FF), 100 for red (#FF0000), what about 50?

Comment: It will change from blue to red slowly.

Comment: Does that mean `#7F007F`?

Comment: The default color of rectangle is yellow so 50 would yellow. i.e. 0 = blue, 50 = yellow and 100 = red.

Comment: In [CSS color keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Color_keywords), red is `#FF0000`, yellow is `#FFFF00`, blue is `#0000FF`, so if 0 being red, 100 being blue, then 50 being yellow would be, weird, as no base color is being transacted linear-ly (thus might not be the "changing slowly" type you thought). It's still doable, though. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: OK then lets make it `#7F007F`. which you already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it using a scale of 0-255, since rgb values are from 0-255.
You could use a little math to be able to use 0-100 and convert it to 0-255 behind the scenes, though.

---

HTML:

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="range" id="range" min="0" max="255" value="0">
```

JavaScript:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('range');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function sliderChange() {
    var value = parseInt(slider.value, 10);
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + value + ', 0, ' + (255 - value) + ')';
    context.fill();   
}

slider.onchange = sliderChange;

sliderChange(); // run our function once to start
```

---

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/gaVs2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go from red to yellow to blue:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('range');
var ctx=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

slider.addEventListener("change",function(){
    var r,g,b;
    if(slider.value<=50){
        r=255;
        g=Math.round(255*slider.value/50);
        b=0;
    }else{
        r=Math.round(255*(100-slider.value)/50);
        g=r;
        b=Math.round(255*(slider.value-50)/50);
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle="rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
},false);
```

If you want to go just from red to blue:

```
var slider=document.getElementById("range");
var ctx=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
slider.addEventListener("change",function(){
    var r,b;
    r=Math.round(255*(100-slider.value)/100);
    b=Math.round(255*slider.value/100);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle="rgb("+r+",0,"+b+")";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
},false);
```

[JSFiddle that contains both two](http://jsfiddle.net/nhXQa/1/)

In "red to yellow to blue" case, the three colors:

- Red: stays at 255 in 0 to 50, then 255 to 0 in 50 to 100;
- Green: from 0 to 255 in 0 to 50, then 255 to 0 in 50 to 100;
- Blue: stays at 0 in 0 to 50, then 0 to 255 in 50 to 100.

In "red to blue" case, the three colors:

- Red: from 255 to 0 in 0 to 100;
- Green: not present;
- Blue: from 0 to 255 in 0 to 100.

---

Edit:

Here's a third option of the transaction:

```
var slider=document.getElementById("range");
var ctx=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
slider.addEventListener("change",function(){
    var r,g,b;
    if(slider.value<=25){
        r=255;
        g=Math.round(255*slider.value/25);
        b=0;
    }else if(slider.value<=50){
        r=Math.round(255*(50-slider.value)/25);
        g=255;
        b=0;
    }else if(slider.value<=75){
        r=0;
        g=255;
        b=Math.round(255*(slider.value-50)/25);
    }else{
        r=0;
        g=Math.round(255*(100-slider.value)/25);
        b=255;
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle="rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
},false);
```

[JSFiddle that contains all three](http://jsfiddle.net/nhXQa/2/)

Comment: Personal comment: I think the "red to yellow to blue" thing doesn't look that "natural", as it's missing "green" in spectrum. I would suggest splitting more "stage"s, e.g. `#FF0000` to `#FFFF00` to `#00FF00` to `#00FFFF` to `#0000FF`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you did inside `Math.round()` function in all 3 examples? They are very confusing. I want to change it to this range `-100 to 0 to 100`. `-100 = blue, 0 = original color of the image / yellow and 100 = red`.

Comment: @2619 Colors are composited in three "base" colors: red,green,blue, each "quantity" ranging from 0 to 255. CSS "red" equals to `rgb(255,0,0)`, as in 255 red, 0 green, 0 blue; "yellow" equals to `rgb(255,255,0)`, as in 255 red, 255 green, 0 blue. So in first "red to yellow to blue", from 0 to 50, I keep red in 255, green linearly transit from 0 to 255, and keep blue in 0, so when in 50, you get 255 red, 255 green, 0 blue; from 50 to 100, red linearly transit from 255 to 0, green also, and blue linearly transit from 0 to 255, so in 100, you get 0 red, 0 green, 255 blue.

Comment: @2619 For example, in 0 to 50, `g=Math.round(255*slider.value/50)` means, g(reen) use `slider.value/50` "quantity" of 255, so in 0, green is 0 (255*0); in 25, green is 127 (255*0.5); in 50, green is 255 (255*1). in 50 to 100, `r=Math.round(255*(100-slider.value)/50)` checks "how close slider is to 100", so in 50, it's 255*(50/50); in 75, it's 255*(25/50); and in 100, it's 255*(0/50).